# Google Charts Bar Charts, View Window scrolling, and Printing PNGs

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

So, I have a dataset that generates a pretty huge bar chart---so big that trying to get all the bars on a single non-scrolling page ensures that the text is just a touch too small to read comfortably.

Based on some reading, I thought I might use [Google's example about changing the view window](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/animation#changing-the-view-window) to scroll up and down the bars.  Works great, everything looks fine...

Until I try and render the printable version of the chart, which renders the bars that are just outside of the view window (and makes the printed chart look terrible):

[image: Text removed to protect my job.]

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what I need to do to ensure that the png is only displaying what's in the view window.

Thanks, in advance, for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for anyone else who ends up struggling with this, the fix is to actually remove the bars that are "off the page" with some javascript/jquery.  I used jquery because I'm lazy (?).

```
$('#ChartID').find('g[clip-path] rect').filter(
    function(){return $(this).attr('y') > 566}
).remove();
```

That value at the end needs to be the y position of the last bar visible on the chart.  I do something similar for all the bars that are "above" the visible chart range.  Make sure to be really specific in what you're selecting for removal from that 'g[clip-path]' business, as there are other elements on the page that might match and also get removed.